# Importing pdf generated by mpdf causes a startxref error

Tags: mpdf

Good morning

I am trying to concatenate a PDF to a newly generated PDF but am  receiving an startxref error

I have tried with other PDF's and the code words fine. It only fails if I am importing a PDF generated by MPDF.

Has anyone else come across this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the code, show the error. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a PDF version compatibility error.

This was resolved by changing the PDF versions to version  < 1.4.

I purchased the following plugin from SetAsign which solved the compatibility issues which was a better option.

https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi-pdf-parser/details/

Jan, the creator, is very helpful too!